# Cross mark is coming in pictureBox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, exception

I have made a dashboard which is showing intensity of camera. My dashboard drawing function is...

```
void drawImageMeter(float intensity_value,short * cambuff)
{

    //Read Image function***********************
                IplImage *Image;
                        FILE * fp;
                        fp=fopen("Imagebuffer.bin","rb");
                        short* Pattern_Data  = new short[width*height]; 
                        fread(Pattern_Data,sizeof(short),width*height,fp); 
                        fclose(fp); 


                Image=cvCreateImage( cvSize( width, height ), IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1 );
                cvSetData(Image,Pattern_Data, sizeof(short)*width);
                CvPoint minIntensityLoc, maxIntensityLoc;
                double maxIntensity,minIntensity;

                cvMinMaxLoc(Image, &minIntensity, &maxIntensity, &minIntensityLoc, &maxIntensityLoc, NULL);
                CvPoint2D32f roiStart;
                CvPoint2D32f roiEnd;
                roiStart.x =(width/2)-500;
                roiStart.y = 0;
                roiEnd.x = (width/2)+500;
                roiEnd.y = height;

                int roiWidth;
                int roiHeight;
                roiWidth = roiEnd.x - roiStart.x;
                roiHeight = roiEnd.y - roiStart.y;
                cvSetImageROI(Image, cvRect(roiStart.x, roiStart.y, roiWidth, roiHeight));

                IplImage *croped_image = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(Image), IPL_DEPTH_16S,1);
                cvCopy(Image, croped_image, NULL);
                cvResetImageROI(Image);
                //cvSaveImage("roiIMage.bmp",croped_image);
                CvScalar result = cvSum(croped_image); 

                double sum = result.val[0]; 
                double average = sum / (roiWidth * roiHeight);
                int max_min = maxIntensity - minIntensity;

                Intensity_Values values = {maxIntensity,minIntensity,average,max_min};
                cvReleaseImage(&croped_image);
                cvReleaseImage(&Image);
                free(Pattern_Data);

                        if(count1 == 1)
                         {
                             count1++;
                            FocusExposure::label7->Text =  Convert::ToString(maxIntensity);
                         }
                        FocusExposure::label14->Text =  Convert::ToString(maxIntensity);

                     FocusExposure::label8->Text =  Convert::ToString(minIntensity);
                     FocusExposure::label9->Text =  Convert::ToString(average);
                     FocusExposure::label10->Text =  Convert::ToString(max_min);
    //******************************************




         IplImage  *Background=cvLoadImage("Dialer.bmp", 1);
        int width,height;
        width=Background->width;
        height=Background->height;
        if(counter==1)
        {
            counter++;
        needle_center.x=width/2;
        needle_center.y=height/2;


        needle_top.x=needle_center.x;
        needle_top.y=needle_center.y-140;
        }


            double const PI = 3.14159265358979323;
           int x1 = needle_top.x; 
           int y1 = needle_top.y;

           int x0=needle_center.x;
           int y0=needle_center.y;
           float angle;

           CurrIntensity = maxIntensity;
            angle = CurrIntensity-PreIntensity;
            angle= 0.0703125f * angle;






           // degrees, not radians
           float radians = angle * (PI / 180.0f);   // convert degrees to radians

           if (current_max==1)
            {
                current_max++;
                int N1x1 = needle_top.x; 
                int N1y1 = needle_top.y;
                needle1_top.x = ((N1x1-x0) * cos(radians)) - ((N1y1-y0) * sin(radians)) + x0; 
                needle1_top.y = ((N1x1-x0) * sin(radians)) + ((N1y1-y0) * cos(radians)) + y0;
            }
           needle_top.x = ((x1-x0) * cos(radians)) - ((y1-y0) * sin(radians)) + x0; 
           needle_top.y = ((x1-x0) * sin(radians)) + ((y1-y0) * cos(radians)) + y0;

           cvLine(Background, needle_center, needle1_top, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), 1, 4, 0);

           cvLine(Background, needle_center, needle_top, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 4, 0);
           FocusExposure::pictureBox1->Image= nullptr;
           FocusExposure::pictureBox1->Refresh();
         System::Drawing::Bitmap ^bmp = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(Background->width,Background->height,Background->widthStep,System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)Background->imageData);
         System::IntPtr hbitmap = bmp->GetHbitmap();

         FocusExposure::pictureBox1->Image=FocusExposure::pictureBox1->Image->FromHbitmap(hbitmap );
         delete bmp;
         DeleteObject((HGDIOBJ)hbitmap );


         PreIntensity = CurrIntensity;
         cvReleaseImage(&Background);

}
```

In this function there is no memory leak. When application starts it run fine but after some time needles of meter frees at a point and then a Red cross mark come in pictureBox and  after that an Exception is coming.

I am not why this Exception is coming.I have also searched on google about this but not found any solution.

Exception coming is...

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_RawFormat()
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle rect)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.269 (RTMGDR.030319-2600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
PUMA_LED_TESTER
    Assembly Version: 1.0.4673.19390
    Win32 Version: 
    CodeBase: file:///D:/VS/FK/Puma_15_10_2012/PUMA_LED_TESTER/Release/PUMA_LED_TESTER.exe
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.269 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.278 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.282 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.
```

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
     delete bmp;
```

Don't destroy a bitmap that you've assigned to the PictureBox::Image property.  GDI+ takes a nosedive when it tries to paint that destroyed bitmap.  The tinkering with the hbitmap is also inappropriate, it should resemble this instead:

```
     // FocusExposure::pictureBox1->Image= nullptr;  Not this but:
     delete FocusExposure::pictureBox1->Image;
     FocusExposure::pictureBox1->Image = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(...);
     PreIntensity = CurrIntensity;
     // etc..
```

Comment: Thank you for reply... I have edited my code as you told me. I have commented these line but same problem is comming..
commented lines...
 //FocusExposure::pictureBox1->Image= nullptr;
 //FocusExposure::pictureBox1->Refresh();
 //delete bmp;

Comment: Well, that doesn't look much like the code I recommended you use.  Not sure how you expect me to help you with that, I can't look over your shoulder from here.  Tackle smaller projects to get a feel for writing good code, you need the practice.

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen carefully what you have recommended.. I have again changed code...
`
 delete FocusExposure::pictureBox1->Image;

FocusExposure::pictureBox1->Image= gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(Background->width,Background->height,Background->widthStep,System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)Background->imageData);

PreIntensity = CurrIntensity;`

but now when application starts it is showing nothing and Don't send error is comimg and application closed.
Please give any suggestion.

Comment: So it did fix the crash and answered your question.  Now you need to focus on generating a valid, non-empty bitmap.  Debug your code, focus on the CV code and imageData.  Ask a specific new question about it and click the Ask Question button to ask it.